# List of Lists with one Element in each list turn to list of items that aren't lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, iteration

I have a list of lists each of those lists having one element. Is there a "pythonic" way to turn this into a list of elements that aren't lists outside of using the loop displayed below?

```
un_list = []
for x in home_times:
    y=x[0]
    un_list.append(y)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists). Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/6340496).

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
sample_input = [[1], [2], [3]]  # list of lists having one element
output = [i[0] for i in sample_input]
```

And this is the `output`:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Read more about list comprehension [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using `sum` *function*.

```
lst=[['5'], [3],['7'],['B'],[4]]
output= sum(lst, [])
print(output)
```

**Output**:

```
['5', 3, '7', 'B', 4]
```